# What are the differences in UX between an iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 Plus that are relevant to an app?

Tags: iphone, user-experience, iphone-6-plus

Previous iPhone upgrades were uncomplicated. A resolution increase just meant an improvement in quality but no change in size, while the iPhone 4S-5 transition was simple since the device only added less than an inch to the vertical dimension, without changing anything else (pixel density, horizontal resolution, etc)

But the 6 Plus seems a bit more complicated because there are two major changes:

1. Instead of the resolution being a simple multiple of the older one, the 6 Plus first appears to draw at 3x to an offscreen buffer, then scales this *down* to 1920x1080.
2. The PPI has changed by a non-integral amount (from 326 PPI on 5S to 401 PPI on the 6 Plus).

This is making it hard for me to understand the following:

1. How much more screen real-estate do I REALLY have on a 6-Plus, in physical terms, on the X and Y axis, as compared to an iPhone 5?
2. Will my buttons be smaller/larger on the 6-Plus? Because of the different ppi and the scaling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The physical ratio of the screens is easily derived from the physical dimensions themselves! Since the aspect ratio has been maintained, the ratio of the diagonals (5.5/4 and 4.7/4) should easily give you the increase in horizontal and vertical dimensions the iPhone 6 and 6 Plus provide over the iPhone 5. 

   Thus, you have `37.5% more space` in EACH DIMENSION (width and height) in the 6-Plus, and `17.5% more space` in the iPhone 6, as compared to the iPhone 5. The area ratios (although less useful) are 89% and 38% respectively.
2. The button-size calculation is more involved. To make things easy, let's consider the render-size (in inches) of a 100-points button. Now:

   a. On non-retina devices (iPhone 1 to 3GS), 100-points translate to 100-pixels. Because of 163 ppi, their physical size would be **0.6135 inches**

   b. On retina devices (iPhone 4 to iPhone 6), 100-points translate to 200-pixels (2x scaling). because of 326 ppi, their physical size would be: **0.6135 inches** 

   (of course we know from experience that buttons are the same physical size as on non-retina devices)

   c. On **retina "HD" devices** (iPhone 6-Plus). 100-points FIRST translate to 300-pixels (3x scaling). They are then scaled DOWN to ~0.87 of their original pixel size (i.e. the 2208x1242 pixel-buffer is scaled to 1920x1080). This means, ***300-pixels are now drawn as ~261 pixels***.

   Because of 401 ppi, their physical size would be: **0.65 inches**

   So **buttons on a 6 Plus are 6% larger physically**, given the SAME point size. For most practical purposes, this is a negligible difference, and can be ignored. And on the upside the slightly larger buttons may even improve usability of your app.

> Thus a button or UI-element of a specific point-size, should have **ALMOST the same physical size** on both an iPhone 5/6 versus an iPhone 6 Plus.
>   
>   
>   **Comment:** This indicates that all the roundabout scaling and ppi-changes were effectively for Apple to achieve both:
>   
> 1. A higher ppi on a new higher-end class of devices
>   
> 2. Keeping the logical-points to physical-inches translation as CLOSE to the original ratio as possible, so that buttons etc remain the same size on all devices.
>   
>   So you dont need to be concerned about button sizes. Just account for the 37.5% additional space available to you on in each dimension on iPhone 6 Plus, and 17.5% in the iPhone 6, in your app and you should be good to go.

Comment: I posted this because I was struggling with both of these questions for quite some time while trying to figure out app-scaling behavior for 6 and 6-Plus. Submission-anxiety also meant I miscalculated the figures for a short while and headed in a completely wrong direction for adding/removing/scaling elements in the UI, before realizing my mistake a couple of hours later. Hopefully, this should help someone in a similar situation.